# mySQL responses "array" at PHP page (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have mySQL Database. I'm making request inside of it.

```
SELECT proc from an_vac WHERE   publ=1
```

Result is 48.

Now I have to display Request result (unique value) at the webpage (I'm using PDO connection).

I request:

```
<?php $result = $db->select("SELECT proc from an_vac WHERE  publ=1");
$value=$result[0];                  
echo    $value; ?>
```

Result is array. 
What's wrong from my side?

Comment: `select()` is not a PDO method. It sounds like it's returning a 2-dimensional array: the first dimension is the rows, the second dimension is the columns.

Comment: do debug yourself first: `var_dump($result)`, see what's in there

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["proc"]=> string(2) "48" } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using some sort of wrapper for working with MySQL, since `$db->select(...)` is not part of PHP or its default extensions. But I can guess that `$result` is an array of rows, and each row is an array of row values by column name. Replace `$value=$result[0];` with:

```
$value=$result[0]['proc'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work better:

```
$proc = getProc();

function getProc() {
    try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=192.168.0.1;charset=utf8", "username", "password");
        $cmd = $db->prepare("
            SELECT proc from an_vac WHERE  publ=1;
        ");
        $cmd->execute();
        $result = $cmd->fetch();
        return $result[0];
    } catch (Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); return; }
}
```